# Event delegation get attribute on click from list

Tags: javascript

I tried getting href attribute with `event.target.getAttribute('href')` but due to event delegation. `event.target` seems to be set to either `span` or `i`.

```
<a href="#gallery">
  <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
  <span class="menu-text">Gallery</span>
</a>
<a href="#download">
  <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
  <span class="menu-text">Download</span>
</a>   


//script
 for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', openMenu);
}
function openMenu(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var clickedMenu = event.target.getAttribute('href');
    document.querySelector(clickedMenu).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Kindly provide some guidance. I do not need a jquery solution.

Comment: Can we see your JS ?

Comment: Hi @RayonDabre I've updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have children for the links, `event.target` may refer to those elements if the click had happened on them.

You can use `this` inside the handler to refer to the link element, another option is to use [event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].addEventListener('click', openMenu);
}

function openMenu(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var clickedMenu = this.getAttribute('href');
  result.innerHTML = clickedMenu + ' or ' + event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
  document.querySelector(clickedMenu).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#gallery">
  <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
  <span class="menu-text">Gallery</span>
</a>
<a href="#download">
  <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
  <span class="menu-text">Download</span>
</a>


<div id="result"></div>

<div id="gallery" class="hidden">gallery</div>
<div id="download" class="hidden">download</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you try

event.currentTarget.getAttribute("href")